# Translate mesh in A-frame along single axis

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am using GLTF models in my AFRAME project and trying to make sure that the translation of object happens in a certain direction.

If the object's mesh has `0 0 0` rotation it translates perfectly with `el.object3DMap.mesh.translateX/Y/Z(value);` but if the object has a certain rotation in x,y or z-axis then it translates towards a certain direction.

How do I make the mesh translate in only x,y or z-axis after the object has been loaded?

-thanks

Comment: Why not to translate objects, using `.mesh.position.x/y/z = value` or `.mesh.position.set()`? `.translateX(), .translateY(), .translateZ()`, those functions internally call [`.translateOnAxis()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ba4489ded66212ac9e6d3017a6bb856023bd026f/src/core/Object3D.js#L231)

Comment: It will show the same behavior.
If we have a function that can position the mesh according to the object3D then it would be great